# Empty Directory Error Handling

Tags: php, error-handling, directory, try-catch

I would like to know how to do a basic Try Catch block that prints a message if there are no files in a directory

This is what I tried:

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'admin';
$dbpass = 'root';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'files';
mysql_select_db($dbname);


mysql_query("TRUNCATE files_tbl");

 if ($handle = opendir('./pdf/')) {



   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {


          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")   {

          if ( ($file = @scandir('./pdf/') && (count($file) > 0) ) ) {

          $directory_not_empty = TRUE;
          } {
                throw new Exception('No files in database');
        } try {

            @$thelist .= '<font face="Calibri" size="4"><p><b><img src="images/document.png"> '.$file.'<br></b></p></a></font>';

            $query = "INSERT INTO files.files_tbl(Name) VALUES ('$file');";


            mysql_query($query) or die('Error, Insert query failed' . mysql_error());

          } catch (Exception $e) {
                die ($e->getMessage);


       }

       }

}

  closedir($handle);
  }


?>

<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <title>Search the Database</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div align="right"><form action="search.php" method="post">
    <div align="left"><font face="Arial" size="8" ><b>Document Database</b> </font></div>
     <font face="Arial" size="5px" ><b> Search: <input type="text" name="term" style="border:1px dashed #216DAB"/></b></font>

    &nbsp;

    <input type="image" src="images/search1.png"  name="submit" value="Search" align="right"/>
    </form>
    <hr size="20" noshade="noshade" color="#216DAB">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

<P><font face="Arial" Size="6px" color="black" ><b>List of files</b></font></p>
<P><center><table border="0" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" style="border:1px dotted black"><td><?=$thelist?></td></table></center></p>
```

However I get a PHP error when I load the php page.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: thelist in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 76
```

TryCatch part:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {


          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")   {

          if ( ($file = @scandir('./pdf/') && (count($file) > 0) ) ) {

          $directory_not_empty = TRUE;
          } {
                throw new Exception('No files in database');
        } try {

            @$thelist .= '<font face="Calibri" size="4"><p><b><img src="images/document.png"> '.$file.'<br></b></p></a></font>';

            $query = "INSERT INTO files.files_tbl(Name) VALUES ('$file');";


            mysql_query($query) or die('Error, Insert query failed' . mysql_error());

          } catch (Exception $e) {
                die ($e->getMessage);


       }

       }

}

  closedir($handle);
  }
```

Comment: This is just a notice not a php error. PHP is complaining about the variable $thelist, which is directly used to concatenate a string: @$thelist .= '...'; To prevent this notice just add a line where you define the variable: $thelist = '';

Comment: yep ... add $thelist=''; just after the mysql_query and the warning will disappear

Comment: @Develman Thanks! But how do I code it in order to display 'No files in database'? I should use a TryCatch no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "$thelist" varibale is not defined

```
<P><center><table border="0" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" style="border:1px dotted black"><td><?=$thelist?></td></table></center></p>
```

Look there http://pastebin.com/jPdeieQV
See line 13, 31 and 76

Comment: But how do I code it in order to display 'No files in database' if the directory is empty?

Comment: Your code didn't work (it didn't display the message) so I tried to modify it a bit. But it's still not working (http://pastebin.com/n2w8Xe1S)

Comment: ssory. In line 26:
if($thelist==''){
 $thelist = '<font face="Calibri" size="4"><p><b><img src="images/document.png"> No Files In Database <br></b></p></a></font>';
}

Comment: So the error message is displayed, but I'm getting new errors on 14 & 15
`Warning: scandir(./templates/,./templates/) [function.scandir]: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 14

Warning: scandir(./templates/) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 14

Warning: scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 14

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 15`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the path. new error is `Notice: Undefined variable: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined variable: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\viewer\list.php on line 18` but doesn't show the error message

Comment: @Brian let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2846/discussion-between-troodon-and-brian)

Answer (score 0):

Before while you should add

```
$thelist = '';
```

Maybe even before if :)

For catching exception you should put

```
throw new Exception(....);
```

Inside try..catch block.

Comment: I tried it, as I showed you in my code in the original question. However it's not working

Comment: You should move try { up and set under if. Otherwise I don't understand where it's necessary to show this message.